# Why is the navigator.share api not sending the full URL in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

Using the navigator.share API to natively share a link to web page on iOS. The iPhone im testing this on uses iOS 16.0

```
async handleShareClicked() {
      const shareData = {
        text: `Foo`,
        url: "https://qa.example.com/path",
      };
      if (navigator.canShare(shareData)) {
        try {
          await navigator.share(shareData);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("no support");
      }
},
```

This opens the share window on iOS. And the preview section shows the proper title and proper URL.

However, when I click one of the sharing mechanisms (messages, email, etc.) the subdomain and the path on the URL gets dropped and the URL that ends up being shared is `https://example.com` instead of `https://qa.example.com/path`

How can I get url and path to be shared?

**Update**: The issue appears to be specific to my origin. Trying with other URLs shares the full URL as expected. My origin is in cloudflare and uses CNAME flattening.

Comment: Does your site have [a `rel=canonical` tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) in the header?

Comment: no...should it? if so, can you provide more specifics please?

Comment: If it did have a rel=canonical set, that could override the share URL; IIRC Facebook uses it if it's set. Are you able to share your URL? Given that it's specific to your origin, it seems likely it's something specific to the code there.

Comment: just figured it out. seems there was some of the facebook/twitter metatags were interfering with the share URL. time to figure out which ones!

Comment: Something like `og:url`, most likely.